# R Studio- Caret Package, commands not working

Tags: r, split, glm, training-data

I have installed the Caret package in R Studio. I am using this package to split the data and eventually fit it into the model. The splitting of data code is below:-

```
library(caret)
set.seed(1234)
trainIndex<- CreateDataPartition(y, times = 1, p = 0.5, list = F)
Training<- dataset[trainIndex,]
Validation<- dataset[-trainIndex,]
```

It is splitting the 50% data into training and testing sets. But when I'm fitting the data in the model using `glm()` command, it's taking 100% data into training.

```
glm(y~ dataset$x1 + dataset$x2 + dataset$x3, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = Training)
```

I'm not sure what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You would better not to use `$` in model when you use `data = ...` argument. Model was using `dataset$x...` so it was taking 100% data.

```
glm(y~ x1 + x2 + x3, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = Training)
```